My subscription is still running even after unsubscribing
I am getting the response from the subscription but when I change the route and come back to my component then the data is still there. So I am still receiving the data even after using unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy.
Here is my code snippet:
Service:
sendDueDatetoPayments = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    
communicateDueDatetoPayments(msg) {
    this.sendDueDatetoPayments.next(msg);
}

TS code:
export class RentUnitsTransactionDetailsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
dueDateSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
    
ngOnInit(){
    this.listenDueDateRes();
}

listenDueDateRes() {
    this.dueDateSubscription = this.sharedService.sendDueDatetoPayments.subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res)
      if (res) {
       //do something
      }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dueDateSubscription?.unsubscribe();
}
}


have you implemented ngOnDestroy in your component?

have you confirmed that ngOnDestroy is, in fact, called?

Is it possible that you call listenDueDateRes() multiple times?

@JSmith I have implemented OnDestroy. Please look at my edited snippet.

this is really strange are you sure you haven't subscribed or used the service elsewhere, please add a console.log to your ngOndestroy to see if it triggers when you change route or component

Why do you create the subscription in the ngOninit? Can you also use the constructor. And please check the following angular feature: https://angular.dev/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed  ... there is no need for the other suggestion because there is a build in feature in angular ... can also be used in OnInit but there you need to provide the destroy ref ... but this is no big deal

Are you sure the component even gets destoryed when you say the data is still there?

Are you sure the data is "still there" or is simply being repopulated because you subscribe to the sharedService method in the ngOnInit? Try console logging the data in the constructor (before any subscription is made) to check if this is really the case.

you should write:
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ...
}

without more code it's difficult to say also look at possible subscription of the same BehaviorSubject in other components
One quick manner to solve most unsubscription problem is to use a Subject in your component as so;
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
...
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  destroy$ = new Subject<true>()
  ...
  ngOnInit(){

    this.sharedService.sendDueDatetoPayments.pipe(
      takeUntil( this.destroy$ ), 
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res)
      if (res) {
       //do something
      }
    });

  }

  ngOnDestroy () {

    this.destroy$.next( true );

  }
}


I've already tried it. This didn't work

import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, inject } from "@angular/core";
    import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
    import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { SharedService } from "./shared.service";
    import { Subject, takeUntil, switchMap } from "rxjs";
    
    @Component({
      selector: "app-root",
      standalone: true,
      imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.sass"],
      providers: [SharedService],
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      protected shared = inject(SharedService);
      private $destroy = new Subject();
      ngOnInit(): void {
        let mapOp = this.shared.getPostAlbums().pipe(
          takeUntil(this.$destroy),
          switchMap((data: any) => data),
          map((data: any) => {
            return {
              userId: data.userId,
              id: data.id * 10,
            };
          })
        );
      }
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.$destroy.next(undefined);
        this.$destroy.complete();
      }
    }


This is not an answer to your question, but I thought it may be helpful nonetheless.
A very nice npm package that I've used is ngneat UntilDestroy
Using this package removes the need to use a Subject and the OnDestroy lifecycle hook at all as it tracks when the component is destroyed for you.
Use it like this:
import {UntilDestroy, untilDestroyed} from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
@UntilDestroy()
@Component(...)
export class MyClass {
  someMethod() {
    someObservable$.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(...)
  }
}

I find this method a lot cleaner and easier to read.

FYI there's https://angular.dev/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed now. It's still in developer preview but soon you shouldn't need an extra library for that :)
